# what is request and response in this Script and How did it work?

Tags: javascript, c++, ajax

I don't know much about the web and Ajax, I read the [Sunshine project](https://github.com/loki-47-6F-64/sunshine/tree/master/sunshine), This code gives PIN from the user and check it , If PIN was correct get accsess.
This is Script in pin.html file :

```
<script>
  document.querySelector("#form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let pin = document.querySelector("#pin-input").value;
    document.querySelector("#status").innerHTML = "";
    let b = JSON.stringify({ pin: pin });
    fetch("/api/pin", { method: "POST", body: b })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status) {
          document.querySelector(
            "#status"
          ).innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Success! Please check Moonlight to continue</div>`;
        } else {
          document.querySelector(
            "#status"
          ).innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">PIN does not match, please check if it's typed correctly</div>`;
        }
      });
  });
</script>
```

This script sends one response and request. and In c++ in [This part of code](https://github.com/loki-47-6F-64/sunshine/blob/3840b3c561ef5d664bda3df72fcc04ecc1377b57/sunshine/confighttp.cpp#L475) gives data from that script.

```
void savePin(resp_https_t response, req_https_t request) {
  if(!authenticate(response, request)) return;

  print_req(request);

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << request->content.rdbuf();

  pt::ptree inputTree, outputTree;

  auto g = util::fail_guard([&]() {
    std::ostringstream data;
    pt::write_json(data, outputTree);
    response->write(data.str());
  });

  try {
    //TODO: Input Validation
    pt::read_json(ss, inputTree);
    std::string pin = inputTree.get<std::string>("pin");
    outputTree.put("status", nvhttp::pin(pin));
  }
  catch(std::exception &e) {
    BOOST_LOG(warning) << "SavePin: "sv << e.what();
    outputTree.put("status", false);
    outputTree.put("error", e.what());
    return;
  }
}
```

now, My question is that how can I directly add Script data to `savePin` function for example with `PIN 1234`, and In fact what is actually the request and response?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "directly add Script data to savePin"?

Comment: The input is a JSON object of the form `{"pin": "1234"}`, the output is `{"status": "whatever nvhttp::pin returns"}`

Comment: I don't want this functionality from web . I want add Pin 1234 directly and Test it in c++

Comment: "request" is the message from the browser to the server, asking it to save the PIN. "response" is the reply from the server to the browser, containing the result of performing the request.

Comment: Add a `main()` function to your C++ program, it can then call `savePin()`

Comment: I cant put something like that and fill one json in c++?

Comment: how fill its input arguments? `savePin(resp_https_t response, req_https_t request)` @Barmar My problem is I dont know how put correct resp_https_t response, req_https_t request in savePin function

Comment: This code is apparently designed to be called by a library that processes HTTP requests. So you either have to emulate all the work that it does, or refactor it so that you separate the HTTP processing from the rest of the work. Then you can call the latter function directly with a PIN.

Comment: Can't you just call (or read the source code of) `nvhttp::pin`, since that's doing all the work without the web cruft around it?

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar, could you help me , how can I implement that capability with c++ code?

Comment: I agree with @Botje. All this code is just related to getting the parameter from the web request. If you're skipping the browser, none of this is relevant.

Comment: If you're trying to do a unit test, you should use a tool that generates web requests.

Comment: Thanks, @Botje ,and  @Barmar, I should call `nvhttp::pin` and call it .